# Access HTML file in maven webapp folder

Tags: html, maven

I have created HTML files that I put into the webapp directory of Maven. My folder structure looks like this:

```
/webapp
   /documentation
      /general
             header.png
      /images
          /examples
             image.png
      doc.html
```

Then I access it via the direct link:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/documentation/doc.html
```

The HTML page contains the following entries:

```
<img src='general/header.png' alt='Image' />

<img src='images/examples/image.png' alt='Image' />
```

The first linked image (`header.png`) is displayed on the HTML page, the second (`image.png`) one is not. The inspection view in Google Chrome says that the resource could not be found.

How can it happen that one image is found in the folder hierarchy, but not the other? Is there a specific rule on how to integrate HTML pages into the Maven web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file extension is case sensitive. Since my files have the extension `*.PNG`, but the extension in the HTML document was `*.png` , they could not be found.